# Does issuing a new Github OAUTH token expire all previous ones?

Tags: oauth, github, github-api

I've got an app written entirely in Javascript that uses the Github API extensively. The thing is if you open it up in two browsers (say Chrome and Firefox) and login as the same user, the second browser's OAUTH token now becomes the latest token - the token in the first browser stops working immediately.

Is this expected behaviour? Is it possible to let tokens live on even after new ones are issued for a user? Or do I need to provide some kind of token store on my server for each user and keep pulling / pushing the latest token to all current clients?

In other words, what the best way to maintain OAuth tokens for multiple clients of a single application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this expected behaviour? Is it possible to let tokens live on even
>   after new ones are issued for a user? Or do I need to provide some
>   kind of token store on my server for each user and keep pulling /
>   pushing the latest token to all current clients?

Yes, I would suggest pulling this functionality into an api and storing tokens server side and providing a json api. Like I do with tastyrepo.com